# How to make a barcode smaller in HTML for printing on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, barcode

So I am having trouble making my bar codes smaller to fit on one page.

There are supposed to be 3 bar codes per row and when I view it on the screen it looks fine.
However, when I go to preview how it will look when it prints they get stuck together.
If I make their width too small they no longer scan.

So, how do I make them smaller to fit on one page while they are still able to be scanned?

I have included the main part of my code below it is an HTML file but includes both HTML and JavaScript. I can't put the JavaScript in another file and have it as a source because everything has to be in one file. Any help is appreciated!

```
<body>
<div width = 100%>

<table class="no-spacing" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width = 25%>

    <div id="barcodecontainer" style="width:125%">
    <div id="inputdata" >123456123</div> <!-- Enter the NIIN for the barcode here -->
    Description : Code128A<br /><!-- Enter the description for the barcode here-->
    </div></div>
</td><br/>
<td width = 25%>

    <div id="barcodecontainer" style="width:125%">
    <div id="inputdata1" >456789123</div> <!-- Enter the NIIN for the barcode here -->
    Description : Code128A<br /><!-- Enter the description for the barcode here-->
    </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td width = 25%>

    <div id="barcodecontainer" style="width:125%">
    <div id="inputdata2" >111111123</div> <!-- Enter the NIIN for the barcode here -->
    Description : Code128A<br /><!-- Enter the description for the barcode here-->
    </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>        


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function get_object(id) {
var object = null;
if (document.layers) {
 object = document.layers[id];
} else if (document.all) {
 object = document.all[id];
} else if (document.getElementById) {
 object = document.getElementById(id);
}
return object;
get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128A(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,"yes","in",0,2.5,.6,"bottom","center","","black","white");
get_object("inputdata1").innerHTML=DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128A(get_object("inputdata1").innerHTML,"yes","in",0,2.3,.6,"bottom","center","","black","white");
get_object("inputdata2").innerHTML=DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128A(get_object("inputdata2").innerHTML,"yes","in",0,2.4,.6,"bottom","center","","black","white"</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to prevent the DIVs from getting mixed up, you need to set the width of the divs with `id="barcodecontainer"` to 100%. This way its content won't get out of its parent `<td>`.

```
<div id="barcodecontainer" style="width:100%">
```

Then just set the width of the "parent" DIVs to whatever percentage of the screen you want, preferable using the `style` attribute and `vw` units other than `width` and `%`:

```
<td style="width:20vw">

and not:
<td width = 25%>
```

In general, I suggest you use CSS instead of repeating the `style` attributes for each element, especially because your code is already built in hierarchy.

Here's [a complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/5jsuqsys/).

Comment: I appreciate the response and when I added your suggestions to my code, the code makes my barcodes dissapear. If you need to see the rest of my code, just let me know.

Comment: @J.Brannan Hi, what part of my code made the bar-codes disappear? The JSFiddle works fine, so it's probably an implementation issue

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will be any help, but I use CSS to control label size and page formatting.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Plain Vanilla JS Code 128B Barcodes</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
 <style type="text/css">
<!- CSS adapted from article: boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/print-avery-labels-using-css-and-html/ ->
  body {
   margin-top: 0in;
   margin-left: 0in;
  }
  .page {
   width: 8.5in;
   height: 10.5in;
   margin-top: 0.5in;
   margin-left: 0.25in;
  }
    .label {
   width: 2.1in;
   height: .9in;
   padding: .125in .3in 0;
   margin-right: 0.125in;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
    .page-break {
   clear: left;
   display:block;
   page-break-after:always;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// The MIT License (MIT)
// Copyright (c) 2017, Notionovus, LLC.
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
var arrayCode128Bin = [ '11011001100', '11001101100', '11001100110', '10010011000', '10010001100', '10001001100', '10011001000', '10011000100', '10001100100', '11001001000', '11001000100', '11000100100', '10110011100', '10011011100', '10011001110', '10111001100', '10011101100', '10011100110', '11001110010', '11001011100', '11001001110', '11011100100', '11001110100', '11101101110', '11101001100', '11100101100', '11100100110', '11101100100', '11100110100', '11100110010', '11011011000', '11011000110', '11000110110', '10100011000', '10001011000', '10001000110', '10110001000', '10001101000', '10001100010', '11010001000', '11000101000', '11000100010', '10110111000', '10110001110', '10001101110', '10111011000', '10111000110', '10001110110', '11101110110', '11010001110', '11000101110', '11011101000', '11011100010', '11011101110', '11101011000', '11101000110', '11100010110', '11101101000', '11101100010', '11100011010', '11101111010', '11001000010', '11110001010', '10100110000', '10100001100', '10010110000', '10010000110', '10000101100', '10000100110', '10110010000', '10110000100', '10011010000', '10011000010', '10000110100', '10000110010', '11000010010', '11001010000', '11110111010', '11000010100', '10001111010', '10100111100', '10010111100', '10010011110', '10111100100', '10011110100', '10011110010', '11110100100', '11110010100', '11110010010', '11011011110', '11011110110', '11110110110', '10101111000', '10100011110', '10001011110', '10111101000', '10111100010', '11110101000', '11110100010', '10111011110', '10111101110', '11101011110', '11110101110', '11010000100', '11010010000', '11010011100', '1100011101011', '11010111000'];
var array5bit_A = [ 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'];
var array5bit_B = [ 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4', 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw', 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0', 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0', 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA'];
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:';

function genBarcode(inputString, intWidth, intHeight) {
var arraySeq = [], i, intChunks, resultString;
var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5;
  for (i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i += 1) {
    inputString += "0";
  }
  intChunks = inputString.length / 5;
  for (i = 0; i < intChunks; i += 1) {
    arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2);
  }
  resultString = "";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i += 1) {
    resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + 'px;height:' + intHeight + 'px;">';
  }
  return resultString;
}

function funcCode128B(strText) {
var j, intWeight, intWtProd = 0;
var strRaw = "";
var arrayData = [];
  arrayData[0] = 104;
  intWtProd = 104;
  for (j = 0; j < strText.length; j += 1) {
    arrayData[j + 1] = strText.charCodeAt(j) - 32;
    intWeight = j + 1;
    intWtProd += intWeight * arrayData[j + 1];
  }
  arrayData[j + 1] = intWtProd % 103;
  arrayData[j + 2] = 106;
  for (j = 0; j < arrayData.length; j += 1) {
    strRaw += arrayCode128Bin[arrayData[j]];
  }
  return(strRaw);
}

function fnNewPage(pageno) {
var strNewPage, startNewPage = '<div class="page" id="page';
  strNewPage = startNewPage + pageno + '">';
 return strNewPage;
}

function fnEndPage() {
var strEndPage = '<div class="page-break"></div></div>';
 return strEndPage;
}

function fnNewLabel(barcode, txtHR) {
var strNewLabel, startNewLabel = '<div class="label">';
  strNewLabel = startNewLabel + barcode + '<br>' + txtHR + '</div>';
 return strNewLabel;
}

function fnShowPage() {
var outerLoop, innerLoop, indexBarcode, txtHumanReadable, strPage = "";
 for (outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < 2; outerLoop += 1) {
  strPage += fnNewPage(outerLoop + 1);
   for (innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 30; innerLoop += 1) {
   indexBarcode = (30 * outerLoop) + innerLoop + 400;
   switch (indexBarcode) {
    case 400:
       txtHumanReadable = '' + 123456123; break;
    case 401:
       txtHumanReadable = '' + 456789123; break;
    case 402:
       txtHumanReadable = '' + 111111123; break;
    default:
     txtHumanReadable = 'Test1' + indexBarcode;
   }
   txtBarcode = genBarcode(funcCode128B(txtHumanReadable), 6.5, 34);
   strPage += fnNewLabel(txtBarcode, txtHumanReadable)
   }
  strPage += fnEndPage();
 }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strPage;
}
 
fnShowPage(); 
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to be super critical, but in my opinion you are using out dated web practices.

I recommend not using `table` and using my little best friend `flexbox`.

That being said, you are trying to shrink a bar code down without it losing its scan ability.

I would try and make a few divs, then from their flex them into the location you want.  From that make them a big or small as you want by resizing the divs.

Comment: So I looked into what the flexbox does versus a table, how would I implement that in my code? Would I just replace the table with flexbox?

Comment: @J.Brannan That was my thought

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with a solution without seeing a running demo of the problem you are facing. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

(Moreover the script that you have included has some syntax errors as well. Missing closing brackets for function definition as well as on the last line. I assume these are just some typos you made while posting the question here.)

Looking at the API documentation for `DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128A` @ https://www.barcoderesource.com/htmlBarcodeAPI.shtml, I can see that the 4th param is `minBarWidth`. You have currently set it to `0`. Instead you can set it to `2.5`, same as the value for `width` param, and see if that helps.
(You should combine this suggestion with the suggestions given by @GalAbra. Those are also valid points)